# How can I dump mysql table without using mysqldump?

Tags: mysql, dump

I need to dump a table for daily transfer.
mysqldump requires LOCK TABLES privilege.  Unfortunately, LOCK TABLES does not apply at the table level, only at the database level, and I don't want to give the MySQL user that much access.
Is there a way to do something like ...

```
/usr/bin/mysql -uusername -ppassword -D daterbase -e "select * from table" > outfile.sql
```

... but have it output in SQL format instead of query result format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the table is an InnoDB table, you can use `mysqldump --single-transaction dbname tablename`.

By using a transaction, it doesn't need to lock anything.

Or you can use `SELECT ... INTO OUTFILE` but that dumps in a tab-delimited text format, not in SQL format. See on [mysql](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/select-into.html) for details.

Comment: oops ... tried it and ran into a duplicate key issue because keys were being copied ... so I'm back to the drawing board.  I need to copy records without the keys so I can insert on the receiving end.  Since I didn't clarify that in my question, should I ask a new question?

Comment: Mysqldump doesn't have any option for skipping the key column. So you're back to using `SELECT <subset-of-columns> INTO OUTFILE` and then importing that file with `mysqlimport`.

Comment: I have exactly the same problem, I use --single-transaction but got the error :Couldn't execute 'FLUSH TABLES WITH READ LOCK'
so it seems that a lock is actually required
PS I've just realized that the answer is old! certainly things are changed now ...

Comment: @Nik Is your table an InnoDB table?

Comment: Yes @BillKarwin

Comment: @Nik Are you using mysqldump from the MySQL 8.0.32 client? See this bug report: https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=109685 According to the comments in that bug log, the only workaround currently is to downgrade your client.

Comment: @BillKarwin no, the db is a 5.7 version, mysqldump is version: Ver 10.13 Distrib 5.7.41, for Linux (x86_64)

Comment: @BillKarwin but the bug you reported seems relevant to my situation, since this db is stored in AWS (thank you!)

Comment: I use  too "--single-transaction --set-gtid-purged=OFF "  like someone in the comments. Strange thing is that the command worked till some days ago, and we haven't change nothing server side (afaik)